# My Rails modal window is not fully viewable on small screens

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I’m using this in my Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-modal-rails'
```

I have set this up to spawn a modal dialog when a user clicks a link …

```
<%= link_to_modal 'Add Race', "#add_form", :class=>'modal_button' %>
```

The following style applies to the form …

```
#add_form {
    display:    none;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

The problem is, on small screens (e..g mobile browsers), parts of my modal window appear off screen and there are no scroll bars that allow me to access those parts.  Is there a way I can make the modal window only occupy the available screen real estate if there is not enough space to fully display it?

**Edit:** In response to the comment given, this is what the screen looks like adding the styles suggested.  Still can't see the dialog or scroll at all ...

[image]

Comment: I had a quick play with the css and maybe this makes you happy enough:

`overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 100%; overflow-x: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;`

Comment: Thanks but even adding htose styles doesn't allow me to scroll or see all of my dialog.  Added a photo of waht I see into my question.

Comment: Can you provide some more HTML code for the modal? Is it contained in another element for example?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give this a shot.

I create online designers with lots of stacked layers that shrink down to nothing, with all layers resizing properly..text and all.

Based on that I will suggest some code like this for you.

Mind you I can only see the screenshot.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #add_form {
    display: none;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    padding: 0 0 56.25% 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    top: 1%;
    left: 1%;
    font-size: 3vw;

  }
}
```